# Spring boot application fails to start with javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am developing a simple spring boot web enabled application. Spring boot Version is 2.2.1. When I start application I am getting this error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters.<init>(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:63)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;

The method's class, javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/shantanu/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.3.0/swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.0.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class
    jar:file:/home/shantanu/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class
    jar:file:/home/shantanu/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.1/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/home/shantanu/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.3.0/swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration
```

I have no idea what is causing this error. I even tried putting exclusions for javax.validations on multiple dependencies but nothing helped. Here's the POM dependency tree. Please help.

```
[INFO] com.ibm.dip:MonolithDecomposer:jar:0.1
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.29:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:runtime (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.13.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.3:test
[INFO] +- com.github.javaparser:javaparser-core:jar:3.15.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:3.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- io.swagger:swagger-codegen-cli:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser:jar:2.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser-v2-converter:jar:2.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-parser:jar:1.0.47:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.5.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.0.1-android:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-compat-spec-parser:jar:1.0.47:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-core:jar:1.2.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- com.github.fge:uri-template:jar:0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- javax.mail:mailapi:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:8.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.fge:json-patch:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |        \- com.github.fge:btf:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser-core:jar:2.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser-v3:jar:2.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:jar:2.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-ext:jar:1.7.29:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.29:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.24:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:jar:5.2.1.201812262042-r:compile
[INFO]    +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.54:compile
[INFO]    +- com.jcraft:jzlib:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.googlecode.javaewah:JavaEWAH:jar:1.1.6:compile
```

Comment: can you delete maven local repository? the local repository's location is C:\Users\{yourusername}\.m2. Can you delete .m2 folder and try again?

Comment: ya tried that many times. Didnt work. Those deps wud be downloaded again and same error would occur

Comment: i experience the same issue with spring boot 2.3.0.M2 is there any advice or workaround

Comment: From the Spring Boot 2.3.0 M1 release notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3.0-M1-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters

Web and WebFlux starters do not depend on the validation starter by default anymore. If your application is using validation features, you’ll need to manually add back a dependency on spring-boot-starter-validation in your build file.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you have both have:

`jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api`

(transitive dependency via `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation`)

and

`javax.validation:validation-api`

on your classpath.

Since Spring Boot 2.2: Java EE dependencies with a `javax.` group ID are replaced by the equivalent Jakarta EE dependencies with a `jakarta.` group ID in Spring Boot’s starters.

For more information check the release notes:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#jakarta-ee-dependencies

So you can remove the `javax.validation:validation-api` dependency from your project.